# Can I set relation 'ParentalManyToManyField' for a field into another app?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I'm new in Wagtail and I create my first blog as it is wrote in Wagtail Handbook, and I want to move definition of BlogCategory to a separate place class in favor to creating Category snippets.

For this I created app snipptes and register there class NewCategory. But if I try to relation BlogPage model to NewCategory as ParentManyToManyField

```
categories = ParentalManyToManyField(
'snippets.NewCategory',
blank=True,
related_name='categories'
)
```

I get an error such

```
File "/usr/home/seilorsamoor/.virtualenvs/wagtail/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: blog_blogpage_categories.newcategory_id
```

I know that model snippets.NewCategory must be defined before  model BlogPage, but please can someone tell me can I do the snippet from above or not? Or what I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` since making the latest changes to your models?

Comment: Yes,  of course.